# Does deleting/reassigning a python list allow for garbage collection?

Tags: python, python-2.7, garbage-collection

I know Python clears the memory of things when it knows there are no longer any references to them.  In my code I am doing simulations of a population over time.

Individuals are born and eventually die.  When they die, I want them gone from memory.  But in the meantime, I've put them into various lists which I've then gotten rid of.  Does garbage collection know they are gone, so will it clear them from memory?  My tracking of memory in my code (through guppy) suggests that somewhere the amount of memory is slowly increasing.

Here's an sample code which would create 4 people at each time step, put them into a list, and then go to the next time step and replace those 4 with a new set of 4.  My question is whether when they get replaced garbage collection will realize they are gone.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,year,id):
        self.id = (year,id)


for year in xrange(100):
    tmplist = []
    for counter in range(4):
        tmplist.append(Person(year,counter))

    mainlist = tmplist
    #do operations to mainlist, but leave it there until replacing it next time through.
```

(and apologies if you have followup questions - I'm on Melbourne time, so I'm going to bed)

Comment: Yes, after each alternate iteration it will be garbage collected and Python can re-use that memory space. See: [Puzzled with LOAD_FAST/STORE_FAST of python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28088157/846892)

Comment: FYI: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268815/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can experiment with this using [`sys.getrefcount`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount) (note that the result *"is generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to `getrefcount()`"*):

```
>>> import sys
>>> class Person(object):
    pass

>>> list1 = [Person() for _ in range(5)]
>>> sys.getrefcount(list1[0])
2  # list1 and getrefcount
>>> list2 = list1[:]
>>> sys.getrefcount(list2[0])
3  # list1, list2 and getrefcount
>>> del list1  # or just reassign e.g. list1 = None
>>> sys.getrefcount(list2[0])
2  # list2 and getrefcount
```

Removing the list (if it goes out of scope or is explicitly `del`eted as above) decrements the reference counts for the objects in it, so if there are no other extant references (i.e. that list was the last place they were referenced) their reference count will fall to zero and they will eventually be garbage collected.

Comment: Is there a consequential difference between `list1 = list2[:]` and `list1 = list2`?

Comment: Yes! `list1 = list2[:]` makes a copy of the references in list2; you can change list1 without affecting list2. `list1 = list2` points list1 at the same list-object; if you modify the list through list1, list2 sees the same changes.